# JSP - Custom Tag - Struts2 with NetBeans 7.4

Tags: java, netbeans, struts2, tags

I've got an issue deploying an application that contains one custom tag I've made.

Every times that I try to test the application, I get this error:

> Deployed application at context path / but context failed to start 
>   
> C:\\NetBeansProjects\\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed.

I followed [**this guide**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm) up to before "**Accessing the Tag Body**" chapter.

I have a little doubt in this part:

> Let us compile above class and copy it in a directory available in environment variable CLASSPATH.

I have to create a CLASSPATH variable between Windows System's or User's variables, but which path I have to put into? The MyCustomTag.java class's path? Maybe this could be the problem.

I use NetBeans 7.4 with Tomcat 7.0.41 and Struts2.

Comment: CLASSPATH is not involved when using an IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse, ecc); it is useful to run Java classes from command line.

Comment: Hi Andrea, I just realized that was not a CLASSPATH problem but something was wrong in struts.xml. 

Ciao!